# Nucleosynthesis of tantalum-isomer $^{180{\rm m1}}{\rm Ta}$

Tags: nuclear-physics, nucleosynthesis, nuclear-isomers

How does nucleosynthesis explain the creation of [tantalum-isomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_tantalum) $^{180{\rm m1}}{\rm Ta}$?

Or what is the best theory to explain the existence of this?
It must be noted that the tantalum-[isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) $^{180}{\rm Ta}$ is not very stable; its half-life being only $8.152(6) h$.

But the [Nuclear-Isomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer) in question is observationally stable.

The relative high [Natural abundance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_abundance) of $1.2(2)×10^{−4}$ means that this is not just some special case, which "might happen". (More than [Trace amount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_element).)

Comment: Just about anything is made in supernovae. The unusual thing here is the long-lived state (although it is not unique in that regard). From various papers it would seem that this isotope does provide a set of restrictions on various nucleosynthesis theories, but can't by itself determine which theory is mostly correct.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for comment. Yes, The main problem -I think- that the existence of this isotope restricts practically all known nucleosynthesis theories. I mean what mecanism is left? This isotope is totally surrounded by stable isotopes; Hafnium (Hf); 176-180 all stable, and Tungsten (W) 180 is also "known" to go only through alfa decay yet being very stable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_tungsten I have my self an idea about Nucleosynthesis process, which works even with this, as it predicts Internal conversion/transition being an important part of the synthesis processes.

Comment: I'm not really sure (but not an expert) on how it really limits nucleosynthesis. Supernovae will make everything on a chart of the isotopes (and likely more we've never seen). Then what we see is the result of all those cascading down through decay paths (as applicable) in to more stable isotopes. The odd thing on 180mTa is the relative stability so that it actually hangs around to be seen. Certainly much larger nuclei are formed, and are still around.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes. -Everything- (Thanks for dialogue.) But there is no decay-path to this isotope.  Hf-180 and W-180 are both stable. (no Beta) There is also few others without a beta-decay path. Na-22, Al-26 Mn-53, V-50. And they actually suffer from the same problem. Neutron capture is possible explanation to them, but not to this Tantalum as it has another interesting aspect, that it's isomer is Stable and exists, but it's normal isotope, is not stable at all. Thus, this is THE key Probe to any nucleosynthesis theory. So if there is some ie, fission theory I would really like to hear about it.

Comment: Remember that supernovae are making all sorts of nuclei, including ones that we have never detected in experiments here - the total density of neutrons, protons, and all kinds of bizarre nuclei is hard to imagine. Out of the nova-ash comes various things. But, yes, people seem to think it is a key test.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for a comment. I see that one possibilty would be the creation through Hf-180m6 which total Excitation energy to Hf-180 is btw. amazing 13.56 MeV. So if any of these excitation states would go through beta-minus decay, that could be one (easy) explanation for the asked Isomer. But it seems that this issue hasn't been really worked out yet.  (-or I simply can't find the info)